# How to define a struct with a tuple field?

Tags: rust

Is is possible to define a struct with different fields, one of which is a tuple? If so, how to do it? If no, why is it not possible?

Comment: Did you try ? Was there a problem ? So ?

Comment: I did. My error was simply that I did not define the field in the struct. I used the field during initialization and the error message was "missing comma", it made me confuse. I searched examples on the web and only found tuple struct and struct with other data types.

Comment: TBH I never saw a reason to define such a struct and I'd even call it a bad practice. If you need a tuple as property and not two properties, it means there's a basis for a new type instead of an anonymous tuple. Remember that such a type has exactly zero cost.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for tuple fields in a struct is the same as any type annotation for a struct: parentheses surrounding a comma-separated list of types:

```rust
struct Test {
    tup: (String, String)
}

fn main() {
    let x = Test { tup: (String::from("Hello, "), String::from("world!")) };
    println!("{}{}", x.tup.0, x.tup.1);
}
```